# Entity framework exception while fetching entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, api, azure, autofac

I am using Entityframework and MVC Web API for my project, below is the code to get entity. Issue is when I am calling One method it throws error

> A second operation started on this context before a previous
>   asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any
>   asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method
>   on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe

I want mention few things, I am using Singleton object for context using autofac and Owin, Api is hosted on Azure and the method from which I am calling this method can **async** or not.

```
public IQueryable<entity> All()
{
    return this.context.Entities;
}

public entity One(Expression<Func<entity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return this.All().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: there might be multiple queries accessing the context at once.  Please post the context code.

Comment: *I am using Singleton object for context*. Only one possible answer: don't.

Comment: @GertArnold I tried not use Singleton but it caused issues, I used `builder.RegisterType<AppDataContext>().As<IAppDataContext>().SingleInstance();` I also tried with InstancePerRequest() but didn't helpfull. Can you suggest?

Comment: @Shahzad Above code I am using for instantiate context object

Comment: open a new context per request. this will get rid of this. you are getting an ambient context, which is highly prone to errors of any kind.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I tried using `InstancePerRequest()` but it cause issue like, linked entity is not being loaded.

Comment: You shouldn't ever rely on entities that were loaded previously. Whatever you need to be loaded, load it explicitly (`Load()`) or eagerly (`Include()`) in a new context instance.

Comment: @GertArnold I tried with `InstancePerRequest()` but as Owin is used in project I have to use `app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);` and in this I cannot bind `InstancePerRequest()` scope I think. Do you have any suggestion?